# drop down list in grdiview header and rowdatabound column change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a gridview that contains databound columns. two columns contain information that needs to be adjusted in the rowdatabound e.g if the cell in the column contains a 2 then change it to display 'code'.
i have done this before, however, now i have a drop down list to add to the gridview header, and the list items of the drop down will be 'all', 'uncode', 'code', now that i have put the drop down list in the header, when the grdiview populates it no longer changes the value '2' to say 'code', it keeps it as '2'. Can anyone shed some light in how i can get it to change back to 'code'

here is the code for the gridview item header/databind

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression ="true">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Coding Stage                     
                    <asp:DropDownList ID ="ddlCoded" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CodedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
                          <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>   
                         <asp:ListItem Text="uncode" Value="uncode"></asp:ListItem>   
                         <asp:ListItem Text="code" Value="code"></asp:ListItem>                                                                                                                    
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("codingStage")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

if you need anymore information then please contact me and i will be happy to provide
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

markup:

```
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblStage" runat="server" Text='<%#ShowStage(Eval("codingStage"))%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

in code behind:

```
protected string ShowStage(int codingStage)
{
    switch (codingStage)
    {
        case 0:
            return "All";
        case 1:
            return "Uncode";
        case 2:
            return "Code";
        default:
            return "All";

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this but what i would like to do is change the information in the column to say 'code' where it says '2'. please see the image above. e.g where the cell = 1 then it should change to 'uncode' where there cell is '2' it should change to 'coded'

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't reading your question very carefully... I updated the answer.

Comment: thank you so much, this has worked if i could kiss you i would. i have been working on this issue for weeks... a trilliion points to you :-)

Comment: :D :D glad i could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the same RowDataBound event, check e.RowRowType to detect the Header row. Once you are in the Header row, find the dropdown with a FindControl call. Once you have the dropdown, save the selected value are text in an instance variable. Then you can access it when RowDataBound fires for data rows.